# Why can't I store data in an Azure compute instance?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I have deployed a Worker Role to an Azure instance with remote access enabled.

When I remote to the server, I see disks C: and D: on the server.

I was told that Azure doesn't guarantee the durability of data stored in compute instance. However when I reboot/upgrade the service, I still see the previous data on disks C: and D:.

When will the data on disks C: and D: be lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local disks are non-durable disks. In other words, not replicated. They may fail at any time and offer you no way to recover this data.

During role recycles (reboots), data typically will survive, but you cannot count on it surviving.

If your software *must* use a drive letter because you can't alter the code base, you can mount an NTFS volume inside a Page Blob (basically a Cloud Drive). You can do this from your OnStart(), then pass the drive letter to your app. **Note:** a cloud drive may only have one writer. So... if you have multiple instances, each instance would need to create its own cloud drive.

Answer (score 1):

Because Azure is a cloud service, the hardware that your instance is running on is not guaranteed to be the same at any given point in time. As a result, you shouldn't rely on the data being present.  Even though it may persist across reboots/upgrades, it isn't *guaranteed*.

See the second paragraph on Local Storage from [this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1674.data-storage-offerings-on-the-windows-azure-platform.aspx#Local).  It makes the following recommendation:

> If you require reliable durability of your data, want to share data between instances, or access your data outside of Windows Azure, consider using a Windows Azure Storage account or SQL Azure Database instead

Answer (score 0):

It will *usually* be there after a reboot, but I have seen one case where I rebooted and something went wrong, so the instance was reset to a clean state. You *cannot* rely on the data surviving. I would imagine the same thing could happen with an upgrade.

Stopping and starting the instances will also probably lose the data, but I haven't checked.

Here's a quote [from an MVP on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/3cd21ac6-aeb6-442b-af89-ae913946b3ba):

> The local disk storage of Compute VMs (whether Web Role, Worker Role, or VM Role) is not persistent. It can go away at any time. The data center has the right to move and re-create your VMs whenever it deems it necessary. This could happen in response to a hardware failure, or simply because the data center needs to be reorganized. When this happens, you lose your VM disk files and go back to your deployment image. It is only a matter of time before this happens. This is normal behavior for cloud computing compute instances.